# Change SQL Agent history Properties without using GUI

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to change SQL Server Agent history values. I would to modify limit size of job history log from the defaults. Is there a way to change without use GUI for AWS RDS Instance.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, anything you can do in the GUI can be scripted by selecting the "Script" button at the top of the dialog/window rather than selecting the OK button at the bottom right. For this case, you will get something like:

```
USE [msdb]
GO
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_set_sqlagent_properties @jobhistory_max_rows=1001, 
    @jobhistory_max_rows_per_job=101
GO
```